# android app crashes unexpectedly when trying to change layouts

Tags: android, android-intent

I wrote a budget program in php a while back to use on smart phones.  I am now trying to rewrite for android tablet which will not always have internet so the php option is not available.  So I am slowly trying to learn java/android but have been hitting my head against this problem for a while.

My problem is after loading my fake login screen and hitting the login button it crashes right when it executes the startActivity(i); line and I can not figure out why as the code was practically copied from ( http://learnandroid.blogspot.com/2008/01/opening-new-screen-in-android.html )

i have 2 java files

MainActivity.java

```
package com.mctrivia.cloudbudget;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
EditText txtUserName;
EditText txtPassword;
Button btnLogin;
Button btnCancel;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        txtUserName=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.txtUname);
        txtPassword=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.txtPwd);
        btnLogin=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        btnLogin=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

if((txtUserName.getText().toString()).equals(txtPassword.getText().toString())){
        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Successful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


         Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CashActivity.class);
         startActivity(i);
       } else{
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Invalid Login",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }

}
});       
    }
}
```

CashActivity.java

```
package com.mctrivia.cloudbudget;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class CashActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.cats);
}
}
```

2 XML Files

main.xml and cats.xml they are identical except caption on cats for login was changed to "a" so i could know that the change happened

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1">

<TableRow>
<TextView 
android:text="User Name: " 
android:id="@+id/TextView01" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TextView>

<EditText 
android:text="" 
android:id="@+id/txtUname" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</EditText>
</TableRow>


<TableRow>
<TextView 
android:text="Password: " 
android:id="@+id/TextView02" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TextView>


<EditText 
android:text="" 
android:id="@+id/txtPwd" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:password="true">
</EditText>
</TableRow>


<TableRow>
<Button
android:text="Cancel" 
android:id="@+id/btnCancel" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</Button>


<Button
android:text="Login" 
android:id="@+id/btnLogin" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</Button>


</TableRow>


</TableLayout>
```

Manifest is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mctrivia.cloudbudget"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="13" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".CatsActivity" android:label="CatsActivity">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

error log:

```
01-18 18:33:48.790: E/AndroidRuntime(386): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-18 18:33:48.790: E/AndroidRuntime(386): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.mctrivia.cloudbudget/com.mctrivia.cloudbudget.CashActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
01-18 18:33:48.790: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1504)
01-18 18:33:48.790: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1382)
01-18 18:33:48.790: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3131)
01-18 18:33:48.790: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3237)
01-18 18:33:48.790: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at com.mctrivia.cloudbudget.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:39)
01-18 18:33:48.790: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3110)
01-18 18:33:48.790: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:11934)
01-18 18:33:48.790: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-18 18:33:48.790: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-18 18:33:48.790: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
01-18 18:33:48.790: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
01-18 18:33:48.790: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-18 18:33:48.790: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
01-18 18:33:48.790: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
01-18 18:33:48.790: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
01-18 18:33:48.790: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try doing

```
<activity
        android:name=".CashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.mctrivia.cloudbudget.CASHACTIVITY" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

instead of:

```
</activity>
    <activity android:name=".CatsActivity" android:label="CatsActivity">
    </activity>
```